# Production quality Python opensocial container and client?

Tags: python, django, opensocial

Is there any production quality library for developing opensocial containers and clients in python and django?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding containers, there's [GAE-opensocial](http://code.google.com/p/gae-opensocial/) which can run in App Engine (should also be usable stand-alone); unfortunately it looks like [django-opensocial](http://code.google.com/p/django-opensocial/) is dormant.  For clients, [opensocial-python-client](http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-python-client/).